# how do i remove the color of the text when you click on a button that redirects you to another page

Tags: html, css

```
  <a class="btn" href="https://www.arr3.gq" style="text-decoration: none">
  <span>
    <span>
      <span onclick="location='https://arr3.gq">arr3.gq</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

im trying to make my button text color not change when i click on the button, and be the regular white text color.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) way to fix this.  Inside your `style` attribute on the `<a>` element, add `color: white`.  It's also good to know that you don't need any of those `<span>` elements nor the `onclick` attribute since the `<a>` tag already redirects the user.  This code should work well:

```html
<a class="btn" href="https://www.arr3.gq" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
  arr3.gq
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine this is [:visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) state browser default color. The code below will override the default color of the visited link. [:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) may be helpful as well.

```
a:visited { 
  color: white;
}
```